# Bulk initialize the char array by "\0" instead of memset()

Tags: c++, c, arrays, char

Usually char array bulk initialized by `memset`.

I found in my project  code the  char array  initialized  by `"\0"`. Also I compiled and checked,  it's Working fine.

My question is this is a right way to bulk initialize the char array?

Eg:

```
char a[20]="\0";
printf("%s", a);
```

Comment: What do you mean by *bulk* initialise?

Comment: It's the same as `char a[20]={0, 0}` which works because of http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p21

Comment: Also the same as `char a[20] = "";` A string definition does not need an explicit terminator.

Comment: bulk initialise means initialise all the elements of  array  to particular value @EugeneSh.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is one of the correct ways.

**For [c](/questions/tagged/c)**

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.9

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members
>   of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known
>   size than there are elements in the array, **the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.**

and, regarding the initialization for `static` storage variables,

> If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, then:
>
> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
>
> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
>
> — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules,
>   and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
>
> — if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these
>   rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;

**For [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)**

Quoting `C++17`, chapter § 11.6.2

> If there are fewer initializers than there are array elements, each element not explicitly initialized shall be
>   zero-initialized.

---

So, in your case,

```
char a[20]="\0";
```

try to initialize the `a[0]` to `'\0'`, `a[1]` to `'\0'` (for null-terminator) and the remaining as `0`. FWIW, `'\0'` has a decimal value of `0`, so in this case, all the elements in the array are going to have a value `0`.

Some similar initialization statements would be

```
char a[20] = "";
char a[20] = {0};
char a[20] = {'\0'};
```

For `C++`, as suggested [in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56428958/2173917), including all the previous syntax,

```
char a[20] = {};
```

would also work.

Comment: Perhaps it's because the code presented is very much C++. (Consider editing out the `cout`?)

Comment: @Bathsheba I actually linked to your answer for CPP part, but thanks for editing.

Comment: @zwol Agreed, added.

Comment: Historical note: the string literal zero-initializing the whole array was added in C99;  old C89 compilers might not do it

Answer (score 6):

It works almost, in a curious way, by accident and is, in my opinion, an exercise in obfuscation. An explanation:

In C++ `"\0"` is a `const char[2]` literal with value `'\0'` (Octal constant with value 0) followed by a NUL-terminator, i.e. both 0 values. In C it's a `char[2]` constant with the same value.

Initialising `a` to that also causes the other elements of `a` to be initialised to 0 too (by the C and C++ standards, the other elements are initialised as per `static` storage duration).

In C++ writing `char a[20] = {}` is sufficient, in C you need at least `char a[20] = {0}`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It works because using an initializer to initialize some subobjects 
(here you're explicitly initializing the first two) causes the rest to be zero-initialized (more precisely initialized as if they were static--namely pointers get set to the null pointer constant even if it isn't all bits zero on the given architecture).

A more general versions of this is:

```
any_composite_type x={0};
```

Compilers may and do still implement such initializations with a call to `memset`

Example:

```
struct foo{
    char big[1000];
};
void take_foo(struct foo*);
int main()
{
    struct foo obj ={0};
    take_foo(&obj);
}
```

[compiled with clang for x86-64:](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fEoXXm)

```
main:                                   # @main
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 1008
        lea     rbx, [rsp + 8]
        mov     edx, 1000
        mov     rdi, rbx
        xor     esi, esi
        call    memset
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    take_foo
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 1008
        pop     rbx
        ret
```

(In a similar fashion, they may and do replace explicit calls to `memset` with
inlined assembly if they see the object to be `memset`ted is small.)